# Search excel with powershell and modify?

Tags: excel, powershell, search

This is beyond me for sure but I'm wondering if anyone would know how this could be done.

I have a list of names down a column in an excel file #1. I run the script and it checks to see if any of those names match any name in excel file #2. Not case sensitive. If it finds a match then change the color of the cell containing the name in file #1 to red.

Comment: Hi @Redazu - it is generally recommended to try out a couple of solutions yourself by exploring resources & experimenting out some concepts. If you get stuck somewhere during development, feel free to post your issue and the SO community will help you out.

Comment: Something to give you a headstart : https://lazywinadmin.com/2014/03/powershell-read-excel-file-using-com.html